# MDM Zinc - Run desktop app in fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, mdm-zinc

Is there an option to allow desktop apps build with Zinc 3.0 (Windows XP) to go into fullscreen? (In Flash itself it works but not in the compiled Zinc desktop app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Window State to "Maximized" in the Window Properties Pane.

Alternatively, you can set the Size Type to "Relative" and set the Width and Height to "100%"